# JQL: Putting function instead parameter

Tags: jira, jql

For now i'm using such query:

```
project = MyProject AND issueFunction in addedAfterSprintStart("General 
Board", "MyProject-20180903")
```

After each sprint I need to change 2nd parameter, to last sprint, I want to avoid it, i tried with:

```
project = MyProject AND issueFunction in addedAfterSprintStart("General 
Board", previousSprint(General Board))
```

but it's not working.

Is there possibility to use function as a parameter, if no, how can I get the same result other way?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the issues added after the start of the current opened sprint ? If yes you should just omit the second parameter of the `addedAfterSprintStart` function.

`issueFunction in addedAfterSprintStart("Scrum Board Name")` return all issues added after start of current opened sprint

See documentation : https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/jql-functions.html#_addedaftersprintstart

If you want the issues added to a closed sprint i don't think is is possible with the `addedAfterSpintStart` function.

But you may find this information on the sprint reports : https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/sprint-report-777002722.html

Comment: Yeah, i wanted to got issues from last closed sprint.